# Cells counting problem

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

There is a 3D grid with cells for which we define its value (0 or 1) as `F(i,j,k)=F(i-1,j,k) XOR F(i,j-1,k) XOR F(i,j,k-1)`, base cases are `F(0,0,0)=1` and `F(x,y,z)=0` for `x < 0 or y < 0 or z < 0` (if at least one parameter is negative).
We want to count amount of cells with `F()=1` in the cube with corners `(0,0,0)` and `(N, M, K)`. Dimensions are about `10^9`.

I'm looking for the fast approach on this problem.
This function produces interesting picture, you may find it [here](http://pastie.org/2325056).

Comment: Note that the `0`s in the ASCII representation represent `1`s and the dots represent `0`s.

Comment: The two-dimensional analogue of this problem, with squares -- how many 1-cells are there in the upper-left N-by-N square in the first slice? -- is apparently a known sequence (http://oeis.org/A064194)

Answer (score 1):

First things first:

$F(i,j,k) = 1$ if and only if the pairwise bitwise-ands of $i$, $j$ and $k$ are all $0$.

Proof:
(by induction on $i + j + k$)

If $i + j + k = 0$, then $i=j=k=0$, and so the pairwise bitwise-ands of $i$, $j$ and $k$ are all $0$ and $F(i,j,k)=1$.

Suppose now that $i + j + k > 0$ and the pairwise bitwise-ands of $i$, $j$ and $k$ are all $0$. Note that not all of $i$, $j$ and $k$ are $0$. Thus at least one of $i$, $j$ and $k$ has a $1$ in its binary expansion. Since all of the $1$'s in the binary expansions of $i$, $j$ and $k$ occur in the lowest place, there is exactly one of $i$, $j$ and $k$ that has a least-significant $1$ in its binary expansion. Let us suppose that that is $i$ and that it contains a $1$ corresponding to $2^z$. Either $j = 0$, or $j-1$ will have a $1$ corresponding to $2^z$. Either way, $F(i,j-1,k) = 0$. Similarly, $F(i,j,k-1) = 0$. Finally, $i-1$ is similar to the bitwise-exclusive or of $1$ with $2^{z+1}-1$. Since this only changes bits that are not in $j$ or $k$, $F(i-1,j,k) = 1$, and so $F(i,j,k) = 1$.

Finally, suppose that $i + j + k > 0$ and that the bitwise-and of $i$ and $j$ is non-zero. Then in this case we know that $F(i,j,k-1) = 0$, and so we are just required to prove that $F(i-1,j,k) =$  $F(i,j-1,k)$. Since they are both in $\{0,1\}$, it follows that we need to show that if either of them is equal to $1$, then so is the other. To that end, let us suppose that $F(i-1,j,k) = 1$, and we will argue that $F(i,j-1,k)$ must also be equal to $1$.

Since $i$ and $j$ have at least one bit in common, but $i-1$ and $j$ do not, the least significant bit of $i$ must be equal to the least significant bit of $j$ and must be the only bit they have in common. Furthermore, $k$ must have no bits that low down. Thus it follows that $F(i,j-1,k)$ will equal $1$.

QED

Thus you are asking:
How many $0 \le i \le N, 0 \le j \le M$ and $0 \le k \le K$ have pairwise bitwise-ands equal to $0$.

Let this answer be $f(N, M, K)$.

Note that $i$, $j$, $k$ must be all even, or exactly one of them must be odd.

The number with $i, j, k$ all even is equal to $f(\lfloor N/2 \rfloor, \lfloor M/2 \rfloor, \lfloor K/2 \rfloor)$. The number with $i$ odd and $j, k$ both even is equal to $f(\lfloor (N - 1)/2 \rfloor, \lfloor M/2 \rfloor, \lfloor K/2 \rfloor)$, and so on.

Thus $$\begin{align*}f(N, M, K) &= f(\lfloor N/2 \rfloor, \lfloor M/2 \rfloor, \lfloor K/2 \rfloor)\\ &+ f(\lfloor (N - 1)/2 \rfloor, \lfloor M/2 \rfloor, \lfloor K/2 \rfloor)\\ &+ f(\lfloor N/2 \rfloor, \lfloor (M-1)/2 \rfloor, \lfloor K/2 \rfloor)\\ &+ f(\lfloor N/2 \rfloor, \lfloor M/2 \rfloor, \lfloor (K-1)/2 \rfloor).
\end{align*}$$ Using this inductive definition and caching (and stopping at $f(0,0,0) = 1$) you can calculate $f(N, M, K)$ in $O(\max(\log N, \log M, \log K))$.

Comment: The formula for $f(N,M,K)$ is off slightly: the number of even integers in $[0,n]$ is $\lceil (n+1)/2\rceil$, and the number of odd integers is $\lfloor (n+1)/2\rfloor$.